# How to use oidc-client in a chrome extension with launchWebAuthFlow?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, openid-connect

I'm trying to set up authentication with OIDC in a chrome extension.

I initially just tried using [chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-launchWebAuthFlow) and passing in a manually constructed URL with the client_id, scope, etc. This wouldn't work, as I was still missing parts of the OIDC spec.

Then I started using the [oidc-client package](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) as a way to make sure I wasn't missing any parts of the spec. This package allowed me to successfully launch the authentication popup, but when it reaches the end it redirects to [extension id].chromium.org, which doesn't exist. The benefit of using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() is that it handles this redirect by waiting for it to happen, closing the window, then returning the redirect URL in the callback.

So, using launchWebAuthFlow() alone, I'm not able to complete the OIDC spec in the request URL. Using oidc-client I *am* able to complete the spec, but it doesn't handle the redirect correctly like launchWebAuthFlow() would.

I need to use these two together somehow, I think. My instinct would be to use oidc-client to generate the correct auth URL with the correct spec, then feed that URL into launchWebAuthFlow()... I just can't seem to find a way to get that auth URL from oidc-client.

Is there a way to get this URL from oidc-client and/or another way to get these two authentication methods to play together nicely?

Answer (score 2):

You should use either oidc-client or launchwebauthflow. I suggest using latter because oidc-client does not support manifest 3. After you get redirect url in launchwebauthflow, basically you need to run another request to get token.
https://roberttolton.com/posts/implementing-auth0-authentication-into-a-chrome-extension

2023 update:
[oidc-client-ts](https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts) now supports manifest 3, you can use it

Comment: Can yo add an example using only oidc-client?